# How to write the negation of a biconditional?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

I have two statements $p$ and $q$ such that:

Statement $p$: Ravi reads Mathematics

Statement $q$: Ravi reads Chemistry

Now, I am required to write the negation of $p \iff q$, i.e., I need to write $\lnot (p \iff q)$, which, if I understand correctly, is, by definition: $(p \land \lnot  q) \lor(\lnot p \land q )$

So, according to me, it should be as follows:

*Ravi reads Mathematics and not Chemistry or Ravi doesn't read Mathematics and reads Chemistry.*

But, the book states the answer to be as follows:

**Ravi reads neither Mathematics nor Chemistry**

Are the two statements equivalent? Or am I going wrong here?

[image: The question (part 3 e)]

Check question 3 (e) for the question asked here

[image: Answer]

The answer for question 3 (e)

Comment: Transfer to another class.  The book is dead wrong and you are correct (Although you can say it a little "cleaner" by saying.  "Ravi reads maths only or chem only but not both and not neither".

Comment: Thanks @fleablood 

As for transferring to another class, that isn't really an option as this is a book from a coaching class (kind of cram school) in India and every Institute's materials have such mistakes

Comment: I was being tongue in cheek.  The book is wrong.  Hopefully it is just a proof reading/editting error.  It happens.  Irritating and makes me made when it does but.... it happens.  Rest assured, you aren't mistaken about anything.....  And sadly some books are just plain bad.  Hopefully that is not the case.  If it is... well, read carefully and trust yourself and ask questions.  But trust yourself.

Comment: Thank you @fleablood Yeah printing errors make me mad too. Thanks for the help again :)

Comment: @fleablood "Hopefully it is just a proof reading/editting error. It happens. Irritating and makes me made when it does but.... it happens. "  Kind of funny how you said "made" instead of "mad" here.  Though, the above doesn't appear to be a spelling error, so it's not so similar after all.

Comment: @fleablood It might also be expressed: Ravi reads math or chemistry, but not both. (Math XOR Chemistry)

Comment: @DanChristensen yeah I figured as much. The neither part confused me then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are exactly right, and your book is wrong.

Some equivalent ways to write $\lnot (p \iff q)$ are

$$
\begin{split}
\lnot (p \iff q) &\equiv \lnot(p \implies q) \lor \lnot(q \implies p) \\
&\equiv (p \land \lnot q) \lor (\lnot p \land q) \\
&\equiv p \oplus q.
\end{split}
$$
(The last expression uses the XOR ("exclusive or") operator, $\oplus$.)

However you choose to write it, it is equivalent to what you said:

"Ravi reads Mathematics and not Chemistry or Ravi doesn't read Mathematics and reads Chemistry.
"

OP, don't be discouraged by the rude or confusing answers in this thread. Trust in your logic!

Answer (score 0):

Your reasoning is correct. You can rewrite the negation of the biconditional as $ (p \land \lnot  q) \lor(\lnot p \land q )$ which is the same as your english sentence. The sentence your book has is equivalent to $\lnot p \land \lnot q$ which is certainly not equivalent to $\lnot (p \iff q)$ since they don't have the same truth value when $p,q$ are both false.

Either your book is wrong or you have misunderstood what the problem is asking. Maybe it was asking for the negation of the disjunction, $\lnot (p \lor q)?$

Edit: Now that you've posted pictures of the book I can definitely say that the book is wrong.

Comment: No, I have copied the question as is...

Comment: Well in that case I think your book is wrong.

Comment: " I think your book is wrong."  Sadly that happens.  ANd it *did* happen here.